# Aegisub error when copy and paste

Tags: subtitle

When I copy and paste within Aegisub, I tend to lose the line I have copy and pasted.  I copy and paste some text, then set the time for that specific line, then commit the line, and then save my work (ctrl S), then if I close Aegisub, when opening it up again, the copy and paste line is no longer there.

This happens when I copy from a .txt  document and even when I copy and paste from within Aegisub itself. The problems seems to happen after I paste text under the audio control panel. If I simply type text there, commit it, save the document, close Aegisub, it is there again when I open the program later. However, since copy and paste is what I do 90% of the time in Aegisub, it's really inconvenient that this functions messes up my work, or rather that I lose all my work once I close the program.

If anyone has had this problem and knows how to solve it, please help, it would save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you've [hit a bug](http://devel.aegisub.org/ticket/1754) so the best you can do is to subscribe to the bug list, and say that you've got the problem too so that it "affects multiple users" so that the bug can be closed quicker...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)